# unexpected output in big decimal class, java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bigd {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);   
        int count=s.nextInt();

        // take  n inputs and put them in array
        String [] number=new String [count] ;

        for(int i=0; i<number.length; i++) {        
            number[i]=s.next();     
        }// end transfer forr 

        BigDecimal [] big=new BigDecimal[count];

        for(int i=0;i<number.length; i++) { 
            big[i]= new BigDecimal(number[i]);  
        }// big loop

        //sorting 
        for(int i=0; i<big.length; i++) {   
            for(int j=i+1; j<big.length; j++) { 
                if(big[i].compareTo(big[j])<0) {
                    BigDecimal temp=big[i];
                    big[i]=big[j];
                    big[j]=temp;        
                }// if end      
            }// inner loop  
        } // outer sort loop 
        //end soting

        //display
        for(int i=0; i<big.length;i++) {
            System.out.println(" "+ big[i]);
        }//end disp

        s.close();  
    }// main

}// class
```

Problem here is when I sort the provided input it adds a zero in front of numbers like `.12`, so it will output the number with the said 0 like `0.12`.

How to output the same number `.12`?

I need to know why a zero is being added.

Comment: is that supposed to be 3 differents examples?

Comment: @jhamon I'd say it was because SO said "this post doesn't have enough text"...

Comment: I tried it out and I it doesn't display it like you said. I tried this: **System.out.println(new BigDecimal(12))

Comment: @AymenRagoubi there is probably a difference between 12 and 0.12...  There usually isn't 0 padding in front of an integer

Comment: understood, I thought you re getting it with 12, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.println(" "+ big[i])` calls the `toString()` method of BigDecimal, and that's how it's implemented, which makes sense, since that's normally how numbers are written.

You could add string manipulation to the result of `toString()`, but I am not sure why you want to.

What is your motivation for not having the zero there?

Comment: the expected output want me not to add any zeros , thats why.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution might be to just do some string manipulation on the standard format generated by `BigDecimal.toString()`, as in

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(".12");    
System.out.println(bd.toString().replaceFirst("^0\\.", "."));
```

Output: `.12`

If instead you want to look at using `DecimalFormat`, this should work for the example input you've given:

```
BigDecimal big = new BigDecimal(".12");
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
System.out.println(df.format(big));
```

Output: `.12`

But note, this will print a max of 2 fractional digits. You can increase this to however many digits you want to see in the fractional part.

However, If you want to be sure to see *all* of the fractional digits from your `BigDecimal` you can do this:

```
BigDecimal big = new BigDecimal(".123456789");
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".");
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(big.scale());  
System.out.println(df.format(big));
```

Output: `.123456789`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a decimalFormat to get rid of the 0 in front.

```
BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(".21");
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
System.out.print(df.format(d).toString());
```